# Truffle compile pragma 4.10

Tags: solidity, truffle

In my `contracts` i'm using ether transfers which requires `Solidity` compiler 4.10. With newly updated `truffle` and `solcjs` version 4.10. I still get the following error using `Truffle` to compile the contracts.

```
Error: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.8+commit.60cc1668.Emscripten.clang
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of Truffle (v3.2.1) still depends on [`truffle-compile` ~1.1.2](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/v3.2.1/package.json#L26).  `truffle-compile` 1.1.2 depends on [`solc` v0.4.8](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-compile/blob/004d58f1a8803c62b430852389946b3835ca3cdd/package.json#L10).

The next release of `truffle-compile` is v2.0.0, which bumps `solc` to [v0.4.11](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-compile/blob/4d1c764d70161c28df6129ce352806e63ff0f1a0/package.json#L10).

In other words, you'll have to wait for `truffle` to finally release an update that depends on `truffle-compile` v2.0.0 or later--or fork truffle yourself and bump the `truffle-compile` dependency to v2.0.0 using a git url (since v2.0.0 isn't on npm yet)

Comment: Speaking of: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v3.2.2